# jenkins pipeline Cannot retrieve .Id from ‘docker inspect docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.1.1’

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kibana

I am trying to build kibana docker with jenkins pipeline.
and am receiving the below error
`Cannot retrieve .Id from 'docker inspect docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.1.1'`

The same is getting downloaded and processed good for elastic search.

Docker file (example from elastic search website)

`FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.1.1`

`COPY kibana.yml /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml`

```
  `  stage('docker-build-and-tag-kibana') {
        steps {
            dir('kibana-docker') {
                dockerCreateRepository credentialsId: config.dockerRegistryCredentials,
                    repository: "employee/emp-kibana"

                dockerBuildAndPush tags: ["6.1.1"],
                    credentialsId: config.dockerRegistryCredentials, image: "employee/emp-kibana"
            }
        }
    }`

  `  stage('docker-build-and-tag-elasticsearch') {
        steps {
            dir('elasticsearch-docker') {
                dockerCreateRepository credentialsId: config.dockerRegistryCredentials,
                    repository: "employee/emp-elasticsearch"

                dockerBuildAndPush tags: ["6.1.1"],
                    credentialsId: config.dockerRegistryCredentials, image: "employee/emp-elasticsearch"
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to your error? I am experiencing a similar issue.